# Loading 10k+ rows of JSON into jqGrid 1k rows at a time

Tags: jqgrid

**Introduction**

I load a JSON object via ajax into the browser outside of jqGrid. I then load the JSON into a grid, which the initial setting `datatype: "local"`, using the following:

```
  $("#myGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json", loadonce: true});
  $("#myGrid")[0].addJSONData(jsonObject);
  $("#myGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "local", loadonce: true});
```

The above tricks the grid into allowing me to load a JSON object without the jqGrid making an automatic call for it (which is its default behavior).

Implementing server-side pagination would be ideal, but not currently feasible in my case.

**The Question**

I need to load about 10-20k rows into the grid from JSON. But that takes several seconds. To boost performance, I'm trying to add 1k rows from a JSON object at a time (which is fast and doesn't stall the browser), but I can't figure out how to do that with a JSON object on my hands. Here is my attempt, which loads the first 1k rows into the grid, but doesn't properly update the pager, and doesn't allow me to add additional rows via `addJSONData`.

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
  jsonReader: {
    page: function(json) { return 1; },
    records: function(json) { return json.records; },
    repeatitems: false,
    root: "objects",
    total: function(json) { return json.totalPages; }
  },
  // . . .
}

$.jgrid.extend({
  loadJsonFirstPageOnly: function(json) {
    return this.each(function() {
      // copy the first page of data into a truncated JSON object to load into the grid
      var resultsPerPage = $("#" + this.id + "_ResultsPerPage").val();
      var numberOfPages = parseInt(json.objects.length / resultsPerPage);
      var firstPageData = {"objects": [], "pages": numberOfPages, "records": json.objects.length};
      for (var i = 0; i < 1000 && i < json.objects.length; i++) {
        firstPageData.objects[i] = json.objects[i];
      }
      // load the truncated JSON object into the grid
      var $this = $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json", loadonce: true});
      this.addJSONData(firstPageData);
      $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "local", loadonce: true});
      // adjust the grid's internal state
      this.p.allData = json;
    });
  }
});
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: "server-side pagination would be ideal, but not currently feasible in my case." - But that's usually the best way. Anything else is probably going to just be some hackish solution that doesn't solve the problem. Can't you speak with management about modifying the server layer? I mean, to me this seems like a major design oversight in the server layer.

Comment: Server-side pagination is definitely going to be implemented, but not for a couple months, and a speed increase is expected immediately, hence this hacking experiment.

Comment: Why you get the grid data in parts? How many column you has? Do you load the data per Ajax or use some another way? Is the interval between 1k portion long or short? Do you use *local* paring of data? Why you need at all to load 10-20k of data in the grid? I mean that the user can't read all the data directly. So you probably want to show the filtered data. Isn't so?

Comment: I have about 20 columns.

Comment: What about other questions?: "Do you load the data per Ajax or use some another way?", "Do you use *local* paging of data?" and so on. Do you get all 10K-20K at once from the server or get the data really in 1K parts?

Comment: I load all of the thousands of rows at once via ajax and use local paging of data.